# Insert th in thead

Tags: javascript, html-table

I want to insert a `th` tag inside `tr` of `thead` element of a table. I am using `insertCell` method of row object created under `table.tHead`, which is actually inserting `td`. Is there any JavaScript solution without using any JS library?

**Update**
Currently I am using something same as solution provided by [Minko Gechev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15000019/1823389) and [gaurav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15000018/1823389). I want to know if there is any clean solution like using `insertCell`?

Comment: Be advised, `th` as immediate child `thead` is invalid and may result in unwanted result in various browsers. The valid layout is like this: `table->thead->tr->th`

Comment: Sorry, My bad, i meant `th` inside tr of thead.

Comment: I fixed my answer with `tr` inside of the `thead` :-)

Comment: I'm running into this as well on 1.0.7. If you load full jQuery it works, but you'd think it would work in the 'lite' version. Do we have any idea why it doesn't work in jqLite?

Comment: @Grummle - I dont think this issue is related to any JS Library. Can you post your code?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do it with vanilla JavaScript. Try this:

**HTML**

```
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First</th>
    </tr>
  <thead>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var tr = document.getElementById('table').tHead.children[0],
    th = document.createElement('th');
th.innerHTML = "Second";
tr.appendChild(th);
```

Here is an example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bgwuf

Comment: Why did you used `children[0]` ?? Why can't it be done with just  `document.getElementById('table').tHead.appendChild(th)`??

Comment: Because the 'th' is added to the 'tr', not the 'thead'.

Comment: It should be `</thead>` instead of second `<thead>`.

Answer (score 46):

You can also use the insertCell method as originally requested.  You just have to change the outerHTML to overwrite the `<td>` created by the insertCell method:

```
var table = document.createElement("TABLE")
var row   = table.insertRow(0);
    row.insertCell(0).outerHTML = "<th>First</th>";  // rather than innerHTML
```

To match the example given:

**HTML**

```
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First</th>
    </tr>
  <thead>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
var tr = document.getElementById('table').tHead.children[0];
    tr.insertCell(1).outerHTML = "<th>Second</th>"  // some browsers require the index parm -- 1
```

Comment: Is this the only way how I can influence the position of the new header cell (`th`) in the header row (`tr`)?

Answer (score 10):

Use `table.tHead.children[0].appendChild(document.createElement("th"))` method instead. Basically you have to create a `th` at runtime and insert it into your thead.

Comment: Why do we have to use children[0]?

Comment: Basically tHead can have multiple `<tr>` as children so `table.tHead.children` will return an array of table rows. One can access them using indexes as `[0],[1]` etc

Comment: Oh, I missed that point I thought we are already in  tr, but we were in thead

Answer (score 1):

You can add this functionality to the native HTMLTableRowElement by changing it's prototype:

```
HTMLTableRowElement.prototype.insertCell = (function(oldInsertCell) {
    return function(index) {
        if (this.parentElement.tagName.toUpperCase() == "THEAD") {
            if (index < -1 || index > this.cells.length) {
                // This case is suppose to throw a DOMException, but we can't construct one
                // Just let the real function do it.
            } else {
                let th = document.createElement("TH");
                if (arguments.length == 0 || index == -1 || index == this.cells.length) {
                    return this.appendChild(th);
                } else {
                    return this.insertBefore(th, this.children[index]);
                }
            }
        }
        return oldInsertCell.apply(this, arguments);
    }
})(HTMLTableRowElement.prototype.insertCell);
```

After this code is run, any new HTMLTableRowElements ("td" tags) will check to see if the parent is a thead tag. If so, it will do the same functionality as insertCell, but using a th tag instead. If not, it will just use the original insertCell functionality.

```
document.querySelector("thead > tr").insertCell(); // inserts a th into a tr inside a thead
document.querySelector(":not(thead) > tr").insertCell(); // inserts a td into a tr not inside a thead
```

*Note that [it is generally **not** recommended to extend the native objects.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/1248889)*